# Strange behaviour of for loop in Swift 2

Tags: swift, algorithm, adhoc

EDIT: As discussed in the comments I don't prefer anyone without solving this question before to look at the answer. This is the idea of Project Euler. Please, only those who solved the question look at the answer.

I can not understand what's wrong with that code?

```
var sDigits =  "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
var iDigits = sDigits.characters.map{Int(String($0)) ?? 0}
var digitsProductList: [Int] = []

for var i = 0; i < iDigits.count - 4; i++ {
    var temp = 1
    for var j = i; j < 4; j++ {
        temp *= iDigits[j]
    }
    digitsProductList.append(temp)
}

digitsProductList.maxElement()
```

The output is 126 - the product of the first 4 character.
The digitsProductList is

```
[126, 18, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

It's unbelievable!

Comment: Let me be the boring guy here for a minute: ["The purpose of Project Euler is to encourage people to think and learn so publishing the solution or working code would render this process useless."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler)

Comment: Ow I had no idea this was some "problem quiz", was a bit curious about the title. I'll remove my answer :)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem, according to the problem statement _Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product_ not the four-digit

Comment: @EricD. I see, thanks!

Comment: @VictorSigler I was examining my code with the known answer. If it works for 4-digit it will work for the 13-digit.

Comment: @EricD.: The [project-euler] tag has been removed, but SO does not  enforce the terms and conditions of others website, see for example http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269920/should-questions-regarding-project-euler-be-allowed. As I understand it, questions that arise from PE problems are not per-se "forbidden" or off-topic at SO.

Comment: @EricD.Maybe the title was wrong but i'm wondering why does the temp goes 1, 1, 1 and so on.

Comment: @OnurTuna See my answer

Comment: @OnurTuna When I posted my comment it was just to discourage people to post complete answers. I understand that your question is interesting, though. Oh, and I knew I was going to be the boring guy anyway here. ;)

Comment: @EricD. No, never :) "Boring" means something different. Here is to exchange of views rather than only examine the codes published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a error in your code in the following line:

```
for var j = i; j < 4; j++ {
    temp *= iDigits[j]
}
```

As you can see always you set the variable `j` to reach the max number of `4` and this is wrong, you need to change your code to the following:

```
var sDigits =  "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

var iDigits = sDigits.characters.map{Int(String($0)) ?? 0}
var digitsProductList: [Int] = []

for var i = 0; i < iDigits.count - 4; i++ {
   var temp = 1

   for var j = i; j < iDigits.count && j < i + 4; j++ {
       temp *= iDigits[j]
   }
   digitsProductList.append(temp)
}

print(digitsProductList.maxElement()) //5832
```

In the above code `j` always check that not reach the limit and always move forward 4 digits from `i` index: `j < iDigits.count && j < i + 4`

I hope this help you

Comment: It worked but i could not get why it worked :) I think I should check it again tomorrow. Thank you very much.